# Print Bitmaps onto other bitmap android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to make my game a bit easier on the phone, so I am trying to figure out a way to print a bunch of bitmaps onto another big one, so I can just do it once, rather than every time the screen is redrawn. So, is there any way to do this? I know there is a way to print everything that is printed to the canvas to a bitmap, but I can't seem to get that to work. If that is the only way can someone explain how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Here is something I tried, but it didn't work out so well

```
Bitmap background; 
Canvas canvas; 

private void methodName() {
    background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, someKindOfConfigThing); 
    canvas = new Canvas(background);
    canvas.drawBitmap(blahblah);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is to create the main bitmap, attach that to a canvas to which you can draw.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

You can draw (parts of) bitmaps to this canvas using

```
c.drawBitmap(anotherBitmap, transformMatrix, paint);
```

To attach the main bitmap to the view you would create a new ImageView, call setImageBitmap passing your main bitmap and set it as the current contentview using setContentView.

Comment: Is there any reason why I would get a nullpointer when it tries to initialize the bitmap the way you did it up there?

Comment: If you just copied the line, it would expect width and height to be existing variables..

Comment: I changed those to my existing ones, and imported Config
Edit: I hadn't initialized my level object yet...thanks!

Comment: In that case, no there shouldn't be a problem. Make sure you imported the right Config, which is android.graphics.Bitmap.Config

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine multiple bitmaps to another big one and reuse that, you already on the right way! Show us what you have done and tell us what the result is. I guess we can help you :)

[update] it should be possible to save this new bitmap to disc or store it temporarily as a variable:

```
private void methodName() {
    background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, someKindOfConfigThing); 
    canvas = new Canvas(background);
    // drawing on the canvas should change the bitmap "background" too
    canvas.drawBitmap(blahblah);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/image.png");
        background.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // catching...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I made a method that I ran to create the bitmap, looked something like

Bitmap background;
Canvas canvas;
private void methodName()
{
background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, someKindOfConfigThing);
canvas = new Canvas(background);
canvas.drawBitmap(blahblah);
}

Comment: I hit enter instead of shift+enter, i edited my comment...but it unreadable, so I will add it to the initial post

Comment: Cool, thanks! I will have to use this for something else down the line when I make my level editor